# Storing information across devices without a database

Tags: data-storage

I've seen examples of web apps that has user accounts and stores information about the users, but does not use a database. I've been searching for a while and cannot figure out how this would be done without a database. Can someone point me in a direction?

Comment: Can you point out an example of one? Databases are just ways of holding information. They don't need to be MySQL or MSSQL or Oracle or MongoDB. They can just be text files or in-memory representations. The server could literally just write out HTML files dedicated to the user if they wanted to. The server could also be making remote calls to another server that has the database.

Comment: For $4.96 per month for a 2GB SQL Azure Database, Why not use a DB?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the data has to be stored somewhere.  It could stored on the client, using cookies or HTML5 Web Storage, but this would make it nearly impossible for the data to be shared across devices.  (Technically, the data could be shared between devices provided that another device maintains an active connection to the web server at the same time; the web server would merely transfer the data between devices without storing it.  However, this would be extremely impractical.)  If the user data is stored in any centralized location, there would effectively be a database, even if specialized database software, such as MySQL, is not used, i.e. just using the filesystem of the server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Some used database such as SQLite to store data, but for other application they simply saved it to a file somewhere in the directory (may be cookies, temporary file, settings/configuration, ....etc).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways of storing data based on the requirement:

Storing data On client

1.HTML5 Webstorage is now available, which store data locally and it can support data upto 5MB and it is more secured and faster.

2.Cookies

Storing data On Server

1. Through flat files that is text file or through XML files.XML is standard in many companies as a way to store data. This is really quick.

Having said that, there are downsides to it as well.